# SAP Crystal report export xlsx slow

Tags: windows, crystal-reports, sapb1

I have the client SAP B1 version 10 running in a Windows Server 2019, All runs well but I having a problem just after installing the RDS Role.

Before installing the RDS role the Crystal report generates the XLSX file in just 2 or 3 minutes, but after installing the role the export to XLSX takes more than 14 minutes.

The server client

```
RAM: 128
CPU: 12vcpu
SSD: 1TB
```

have no sense, because before the RDS role worked perfectly
I tested with Windows Server 2016 to 2022, with clean installation.

Fix the error :(